# Eliminar tablas intermedias en un json Response en Sequelize

Tags: nodejs, sequelize.js

Tengo la siguiente query en sequelize

```
const product = await products.findAll({
            where: {
                idProduct
            },
            attributes: ['idProduct', 'name'],
            include: [{
                model: groups,
                attributes: ['idGroup'],
                include: [{
                    model: users,
                    attributes: ['idUser', 'firstname', 'lastName'],
                    include: [{
                        model: roles,
                        attributes: ['idRole', 'name'],
                    }]
                }]
            }],

        })
```

Y el response tira esto:

```
{
        "idProduct": 1,
        "name": "Aviation",
        "groups": [
            {
                "idGroup": 1,
                "users": [
                    {
                        "idUser": 1,
                        "firstname": "Andres",
                        "lastName": "Garcia",
                        "role": {
                            "idRole": 1,
                            "name": "admin"
                        },
                        "groups_has_users": {
                            "createdAt": "2022-06-07T15:37:12.000Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2022-06-07T15:37:12.000Z",
                            "groupIdGroup": 1,
                            "userIdUser": 1
                        }
                    },
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para eliminar la data de la tabla que intermedia(groups_has_users)? ya que esa información es innecesaria para mí y solo ocupa espacio y memoria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que usar la opción "through" después de groups!
Viene en la documentación de sequelize "Eager loading with Many-to-Many relationships". Entonces sería algo así:

```
const product = await products.findAll({
        where: {
            idProduct
        },
        attributes: ['idProduct', 'name'],
        include: [{
            model: groups,
            attributes: ['idGroup'],
            through: { attributes: [] },
            include: [{
                model: users,
                attributes: ['idUser', 'firstname', 'lastName'],
                include: [{
                    model: roles,
                    attributes: ['idRole', 'name'],
                }]
            }]
        }],

    })
```